# Loop a jQuery selection in order of tab-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

So I have a varying amount of form inputs, and depending on how the app is set up in the CMS, they can be on different 'pages' (just show/hide pages within the same document). Which means that their tab-index doesn't necessarily follow the DOM structure.

They're also varying form types.

How would I go about looping through (validating) in order of the tab-index?

(note: the tab-index doesn't always follow an incremental pattern, as the 'next' button on one of the show/hide buttons also has a tab-index)

I have thought about something like this:

```
var $inputs = $('input[type="text"], select, input[type="radio"]'),
numInputs = $inputs.length,
numInputsChecked = 0,
tabIndex = 0;

while(numInputs != numInputsChecked){
  var $input = $inputs.filter(function(){
     return $(this).attr("tabindex") == tabIndex;
  });
  if($input.length){
     // Do validation code
     numInputsChecked++;
  }

  tabIndex++;
}
```

but I believe there should be a better way of achieving this task. (note, I haven't actually tested this code, I'm just attempting to illustrate what I am thinking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will do it, but there may be a more elegant way (I didn't put much time into this):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2" />
<select tabindex="4"></select>
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" />
```

JS:

```
/**
 * Sort arrays of objects by their property names
 * @param {String} propName
 * @param {Boolean} descending
 */
Array.prototype.sortByObjectProperty = function(propName, descending){
    return this.sort(function(a, b){
        if (typeof b[propName] == 'number' && typeof a[propName] == 'number') {
            return (descending) ? b[propName] - a[propName] : a[propName] - b[propName];
        } else if (typeof b[propName] == 'string' && typeof a[propName] == 'string') {
            return (descending) ? b[propName] > a[propName] : a[propName] > b[propName];
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    });
};
$(function(){
    var elms = [];
    $('input, select').each(function(){
        elms.push({
            elm: $(this),
            tabindex: parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'))
        })
    });
    elms.sortByObjectProperty('tabindex');

    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        var $elm = elms[i].elm;
        console.log($elm.attr('tabindex'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors return an array of elements in DOM order by default. See [http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3AjQuery_1.3.2](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3.2).

However, you could add custom selector behaviour by extending jQuery's default selector, see: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/,
sorting your array of selected inputs using a technique similar to [this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/). Remember to ignore the parts that actually rearrange the elements.

Comment: Yeah, you can use the code I submitted in my answer to create a custom jQuery selector.

Comment: @Dale - Yep I think I'll do exactly that! A combination of both answers! But now I have the dilemma of which one to select as correct =\

Answer (score 0):

As said, sorting objects is kind of none-sense ; Anyway, still you can use Array prototype. ...

Does your needs worth writting all that code ?

What do you mean by "better way " ?

-> choose the less greedy method (functions calls, caching objects etc..)

I think your code is okey, may be you could optimize your code and get ride off checked inputs :

```
  var $input = $inputs.filter(function(){
       return $(this).attr("tabindex") == tabIndex;
  });
  // Preventing your code from processing this element upon next loop if any.
  $inputs = $inputs.not($input);
```

But this really makes sense while processing on hudge node collections ...